# Ada - Can't find library info for "check_positive.adb"

Tags: ada, gnat

I have to learn Ada so I can write an interpreter for it. But I cannot find many resources on learning the language. I get the above message when attempting to compile the following code: I save the file as `check_positive.adb`. What else am I supposed to do? I ran `gnatls Check_Positive.adb` after I ran `gnatchop -w Check_Positive.adb`. I am using GNAT Community v5.1.0.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Check_Positive is
   N : Integer;
begin
   Put ("Enter an integer value: ");  -- Put a String
   Get (N);  --  Read in an integer value
   if N > 0 then
      Put (N);  --  Put an Integer
      Put_Line (" is a positive number");
   end if;
end Check_Positive;
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? And which command and parameters do you give when trying to compile?

Comment: @egilhh; I updated the question.

Comment: About finding resources to learn Ada, this is not a difficult task. Just check https://www.adaic.org/learn/materials and more specifically https://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/#tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnatls` and `gnatchop` will not compile your code, you should try `gnatmake`:

`gnatmake check_positive.adb`

be aware that GNAT expects lower-case filenames and one procedure/function/package spec/package body per file. If you organize your code that way, you won't need gnatchop.